# React Select options data from ajax

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Using

```
<Select
    native
    value={item.resolution}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    inputProps={{
        name: 'student',
        id: 'student',
        data_id: index
    }}
>
    { this.state.students ? this.state.students.map((res, i) => (
        <option key={index+i} value={res.id}>{res.name}</option>
    )): ''}
</Select>
```

In constructor

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        students: []
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.getOptions()
}

async getOptions(){
    const res = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
    const data = res.data

    const options = data.map(d => ({
        "value" : d.id,
        "label" : d.name
    }))
    this.setState({students: options})
}
```

All Ok, but selected is showing as below

[image]

How to fix?

Comment: Which library are you using?

Comment: Material UI https://material-ui.com/

Comment: Not very sure about your problem, have created a Sandbox, https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-waterfall-6cwgy?file=/src/MySelect.js

Comment: Really it happens in my redux has a default value, initially students has no value, after getting value is not updating the component.

Answer (score 0):

Try and set selected value aswell

```js
<Select
    native
    value={item.resolution}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    inputProps={{
        name: 'student',
        id: 'student',
        data_id: index
    }}
>
    { this.state.students ? this.state.students.map((res, i) => (
        <option key={index+i} value={res.id} selected={i === 0}>{res.name}</option>
    )): ''}
</Select>
```

Answer (score 0):

If students is equal to options, so, students will have value and label properties only

```
const options = data.map(d => ({
    "value" : d.id,
    "label" : d.name
}))
```

res.id and res.name should be undefined

```
 <option key={index+i} value={res.id} selected={i === 0}>{res.name}</option>
```

EDIT: suggestion

I think this line:

```
this.state.students ? this.state.students.map((res, i) => (
        <option key={index+i} value={res.id} selected={i === 0}>{res.name}</option>
    )): ''
```

will look better this way:

```
this.state.students && this.state.students.map((res, i) => (
        <option key={index+i} value={res.id} selected={i === 0}>{res.name}</option>))
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved this problems with

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            loading: true
        }
}
```

and then

```
{!this.state.loading? this.props.items.map((item, index) => (

))}
```